# Insert e-mail address into input from div when link clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, insert

I have a wordpress web-site where guests can add posts from front-end.

In each post there are some `<li>` tags with certain text. One of `<li>` tags has an e-mail address. It looks like this `<li class="E-mail">example@example.com</li>`. In each post there is author's e-maill address and next to it there is a button SEND MESSAGE. When a guest clicks the SEND button a popup window appears with following fields: send to, your e-mail, your message... I want the e-mail address of author to be automatically added from `<li>` to the SEND TO field in popup window.

There is a list of added posts on a page. Each post is in the tag `<article>` and each article tag has an ID. Looks like this `<article id="post-145">`

Inside `<article>` tag there is `<ul>` with e-mail address.

Please, see the following code as an example. I need to paste email from li tag to the input tag in popup window.

```html
   

<article id="post-145">
  <div class="aside">
    <ul>
      <li class="name"> Mark </li>
      <li class="phone-no"> 911 </li>
      <li class="E-mail"> example@example.com — <a href="" class="popup-open-link">Send Message</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</article>

<div class="popup-window">
  <form>
    Send to: <input type="text" value="example@example.com" /> Your e-mail: <input type="text" value="" /> Your message: <input type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE" />
  </form>
</div>
```

How to do it using JS or maybe smth else?

Please, help. I am looking for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery for solution. Steps are below

1. extract email ids from `li` tags with the function
2. set emailid into popup window's email id field

have a look into code snippet.

```js
function extractEmailId (text){
    return text.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
}


$('.popup-open-link').on("click", function(){
   var emailid = extractEmailId( $('.E-mail').text()).join('\n');
  $('#mailid').val( emailid );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<article id="post-145">
  <div class="aside">
    <ul>
      <li class="name"> Mark </li>
      <li class="phone-no"> 911 </li>
      <li class="E-mail"> example@example.com — <a href="#" class="popup-open-link">Send Message</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</article>

<div class="popup-window">
  <form>
    Send to: <input type="text" value="example@example.com" id="mailid" /> Your e-mail: <input type="text" value="" /> Your message: <input type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Jquery and CSS, you may use the following code to get the current `<li>`'s data-value. 
And in html, set your data-value for each `<li>`, declare id for the textbox:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    $(".popup-open-link").click(function() {
      txtSender.value = $(this).closest("li").attr('data-value');
    });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<article id="post-145">
  <div class="aside">
    <ul>
      <li class="name">M1ark </li>
      <li class="phone-no">1911 </li>
      <li class="E-mail" data-value="1example@example.com">1example@example.com — <a class="popup-open-link">Send Message</a> </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li class="name">Mark </li>
      <li class="phone-no">911 </li>
      <li class="E-mail" data-value="example@example.com">example@example.com — <a class="popup-open-link">Send Message</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</article>

<div class="popup-window">
  <form>
    Send to:
    <input type="text" id="txtSender" value="" /> Your e-mail:
    <input type="text" value="" /> Your message:
    <input type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Vanilla JS Version

> You don't need jQuery for something this simple.

Answer details included via comments.

```
<article id="post-145">
  <div class="aside">

    <ul>
      <!-- BE SURE TO FIX YOUR `calss` TYPOS! -->
      <li class="name"> Mark </li>
      <li class="phone-no"> 911 </li>
      <!-- 
        Using `href="javascript:void(0)"` avoids unneccessary
        uncertainties when using an anchor tag for this purpose.
      -->
      <li class="E-mail"> example@example.com — 
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="popup-open-link">
          Send Message
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</article>
```

...

```
    <!--
    NOTE: 
      Corrected from `type="text"` to `type="email"`. 
      This will provide additional validation.

      Also added the correct `<label>` elements accordingly,
      and `name` properties. 

      It is best practice to manipulate and access DOM
      form inputs via the `name` property, not `id`.
    -->

    <label for="send-to">Send to:</label> 
    <input name="send-to" type="email" value=""/> 

    <label>Your e-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" value="" /> 

    <label>Your message:</label> 
    <input type="text" value="" />

    <input type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE"/>

  </form>
</div>
```

...

```
<!-- 
  Other answers included waiting for a "onload" event. 
  This is unneccessary as long as you insert the script
  *after* the `<article>`.
-->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* 
  encapsulates the JavaScript to avoid bugs 
  via conflicting code.
*/
;(function () {

  function extractEmail (text) {
    var emailRegex = /([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi;
    return text.match(emailRegex)[0];
  }

  function populateMessageSendToFieldWithAuthorEmail () {
    var authorEmailListItem = document.querySelector('.E-mail');
    var messageForm = document.querySelector('.popup-window form');
    messageForm['send-to'].value = extractEmail(
      authorEmailListItem.innerText
    );
  }

  function addListenerToTriggerElement () {
    var triggerElement = document.querySelector('.popup-open-link');
    triggerElement.addEventListener(
      'click', 
      populateMessageSendToFieldWithAuthorEmail
    );
  }

  addListenerToTriggerElement();

})();
</script>
```